¿porque me sale error al escribir get.password();?
estoy creando un sistema de ventas, me estoy guiando de un tutorial pero al escribir get.password() me sale como error alguien me puede ayudar y explicar el porque.

public class Login extends javax.swing.JFrame {
    
        public Login() {
            initComponents();
            this.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        }
        
        public void valodar() {
                String correo = txtCorreo.getText();
                String pass = String.valueOf(txt Pass.getPassword());
                if (!"".equals(correo) || !"".equals(pass)) {
                    login lg new login();
                    LoginDAO login = new LoginDAO();
                }


¡Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en español! Te invito a hacer el [tour].Por favor no publiques código o mensajes de error/trazas de pila en imágenes, publica directamente el texto del código, el texto de los errores y los stack traces. Esto hace que sea menos complicado, para quien quiera ayudarte, investigar sobre el tema y hacer sus propias pruebas/adaptaciones al código, al escribir una respuesta y de esa forma aumenta tus posibilidades de encontrar la ayuda que buscas. Un saludo.

Mencionas que hay un error, pero no indicas cuál es y, como puedes comprender, esta información es vital para poder entender cuál es el problema y probablemente sea el punto de partida para que un experto en tema pueda ayudarte a resolver la situación en que te encuentras. De otra forma, se hace muy difícil responderte. Encontrarás más información en [ask] y [mcve]. Un saludo.

Siempre agrega tu código como texto y agrega el error que obtienes para que la ayuda de la comunidad sea mejor y más rápida, saludos.

Porque el valor de campo contraseña no lo puedes convertir a String, lo tienes que convertir a char[].
Intentalo así:
char[] arrayP = txt_Password.getPassword();
String pass = new String(arrayP);


igual me sale error @Macx

Quizás pueda ayudar saber el error del que se trata, no crees?

Por el código que puso, supuse que se trataba de un jPasswordField, en un login tambien trate de pasar el valor dentro de este y me marcaba error, el código que puse fue como lo solucione para obtener el valor dentro de este

Tanto txtCorreo como txtPass, son dos vistas, para obtener el texto en ambas debes usar getText(), por lo tanto, en lugar de llamar .getPassword() llama a .getText(), realiza el cambio como lo haces para obtener el valor de correo :
String correo = txtCorreo.getText();
//* Error String pass = txtPass.getPassword();
String pass = txtPass.getText();

